# "Flexible Field" for Drupal

Tags: entities

I am sorry for the vague question but I have no idea about where to start.

Please think of a scenario that, you created a **video** content type and you want your site visitor either **upload** their video files to your site, or they use the **embed codes** from any third party providers (youtube, vimeo etc.). For the sake of providing a clean GUI, you do not want to show both fields, but based on the choice of your user (maybe an image combo), you either show the **file upload field** or **text area field** (where they put the embed code in)

My question is, I wonder if there any elegant way to do it in Drupal without making any PHP, HTML or CSS modification?

Comment: Why this community is biased to down vote without making any comments?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this without any level of code. I would add both fields, and then stick some [`#states`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) logic on top of the UI to only show one field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in the past by adding a drop down that gives the user an option of selecting "embed" or "upload"  then use the [Conditional fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module to show or hide the required field.

Comment: Since the conditional fields module is using the states system, this seems like a great idea. Hadn't heard of the module before. +1.

Comment: That's excellent. Even though it is in dev branch for a long time, it works quite well as I tested in simplytest.